# Vertical alignment option of label greyed out in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, labeling

After checking the “render as html”, the vertical alignment was disable.

How do I control the vertical alignment by html or other methods?

[image]

Comment: Could you please specify the QGIS version and also the OS that you have it installed?

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.16 Long Term Release Version. Thanks!

Comment: and using Window 10.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because when you select 'Render as HTML' QGIS is expecting you to enter HTML code and expressions. This code would contain the necessary alignment options.

Check the documentation here:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_label.html

you can see in the example they have given, they use

```
<p align=center>
```

which renders the reference image into the center of the label item.
So in order to align your text with vertical alignments, find the relevant HTML/CSS tags for those line items.

Try this reference here
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-vertically-align-a-text-within-an-html-span-tag.html

It talks about using 'text-align' tag within a span.
Hope this helps.